# App widget not shown on android 4.XX jellybean

Tags: android, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

I have an application and I have also created an app widget for it. The app widget is just a shortcut to launch application.

**My manifestfile:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hansem.handbookmanual"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <receiver android:name="com.example.HandbookAppWidgetProvider" android:label="abc">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/widget1_info" />
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.BrowserLauncherActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Widget1_info.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:minWidth="72dp"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:minResizeHeight="72dp"
    android:resizeMode="vertical"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget1">

</appwidget-provider>
```

**Widget1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button_applaunch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried all the solution mentioned on Stackflow but noting helped. On restarting the device, the widget gets added, but normally by just installing the app on phone and launching it, the widget is not added.

**AppWidgetProviderCode:**

```
public class HandbookAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");

  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    Log.i("ExampleWidget",  "Updating widgets " + Arrays.asList(appWidgetIds));

    // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this
    // provider
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

      // Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity
      Intent intent = new Intent(context, BrowserLauncherActivity.class);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

      // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
      // to the button
      RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget1);
      views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button_applaunch, pendingIntent);

      // To update a label
      //views.setTextViewText(R.id.widget1label, df.format(new Date()));

      // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app
      // widget

      appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
  }
}
```

Please help

Comment: Do you have an activity? Did you run the activity prior to trying to add the app widget? What sort of device/emulator are you seeing this behavior on? Are you using the stock home screen implementation for that device, or have you installed some replacement?

Comment: yes I do have an activity. And i run it prior to adding widget. I am testing on galaxy S3. Yes, using stock home implementation.

Comment: @CommonsWare . I have seen you answer in other similar post where you mentioned that launching the activity should fix this. How can I be assured that activity is launched before my broadcast receiver is identified by system?

Comment: "launching the activity should fix this" -- I would phrase it more as "it might help". "How can I be assured that activity is launched before my broadcast receiver is identified by system?" -- I am sorry, but I do not understand this question. But this is why I suggested that you manually launch your activity; you claim to have done so and suggested that it had no effect. In that case, perhaps it's an issue with the S3's home screen implementation, where it does not reload new app widget providers until a reboot or something.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes I do make sure that I launch my activity manually but didn't help. Yes probably it seems to be some issue with the phone. Thanks for your help though..